# How to get dimensions of a video in React native?

Tags: react-native, video, react-native-video

I am using [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/API.md) component to play a video.

**Problem**:
I would like to know the dimensions of the video so I can adapt some other items.

When I store the ref with

```
<Video
    ref={ref => setVideoRef(ref)}
    resizeMode={'contain'}
/>
```

I can access `videoRef.props.scaleX` and `videoRef.props.scaleY`, but they are always undefined, even if the video is fully loaded. How can I access the video shape/ dimensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a callback to the `onLoad` prop, which will receive the `naturalSize` of the video. Example:

```js
  <Video
    onLoad={({ naturalSize }) => {
      console.log(naturalSize.width, naturalSize.height);
    })}
    ...
```

The callback has a lot more info if you need it - [see more in the docs](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/API.md#onload).